# Sequential Mann Kendall test for a dataset containing custom date format

Tags: r, machine-learning, time, trend

I've been struggling for days with the R script implemented to do the Sequential Mann Kendall test for the rainfall dataset. The dataset format is
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImwHg.png).

Here Jan-1 represents 1/1/1901.

And the x-axis of the plot shows integers instead of the year/date.
[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJryZ.png)

Here is my code,

```
innovtrend <-  function(dataset_updated, column, column_name) {
  attach(dataset_updated)
  column_vector <- dataset_updated[[column]]
  #View(x) # uncomment to view 
  x=column_vector
       
 
  #write.csv(cbind(fh,sh,ten_LB95,ten_UB95,ten_LB90,ten_UB90,S,D,CLlower90,CLupper90,CLlower95,CLupper95,CLlower99,CLupper99), csv_path)
  
  # create png file name using the filename
  filename <- paste(column, ".png")
  # create a path to save png file
  save_path = paste("E:\\4-1 papers\\project\\sqmk\\images\\", filename, sep="")
  # to save as png open device
  png(file=save_path, width= 865, height = 540)
  
  sqmk(x,1901)
  
  
  # close device so it can be saved as png
  dev.off()
}
```

It seems to have something to do with the date format. I want years in the x-axis.

Comment: `library(trendchange)` might be put above as it provides `sqmk`, and link to `x`, the data in question, would likely also be useful.